# to_string returning the ascii value

Tags: c++, recursion

This is a program to print the subsequences and thei ascii values using recursion

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sub(string str,string ans)
{

    if(str.length()==0)
    {
        cout<<ans<<endl;
        return;
    }
    string ros=str.substr(1);
    char ch=str[0];
    sub(ros,ans);
    sub(ros,ans+to_string(ch));/*here why is to_string function returning the ascii value of the character (in the place of to_string(ch) i was supposed to provide the ascii value*/
    sub(ros,ans+ch);
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"Enter a string:"<<endl;
    cin>>str;
    sub(str,"");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `to_string` converts a number to string if you want to just add a `string s` to a `char c` just use `a+c`. by the way what is the question?

Comment: It's about printing all the subsequences and ASCII value of the string using recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is to_string function returning the ascii value of the character

There is no `std::to_string(char)`, so the best matching function is chosen, in this case it's (most probably) `std::to_string(int)`. `std::to_string(int)` just prints the number in decimal, as-if by using `printf("%d", value)`. See
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string .